# Drop-down list from cell formula (not data validation)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-data-validation

I am trying to make a triplet dependent drop-list. The first is a typical drop down but the next two are dynamic.

Since you cannot enter a formula into the data validation criteria, how can you create a drop-down box in the cell formula?

The examples I find often use "array formula"

```
=arrayformula(IF(A1="x", INDIRECT("NamedRangeX"), IF(...) ))
```

but using this function will not turn the cell into a drop-down list, it will fill in the cells below which is the wrong functionality.

What I need is something like this and to have it work with NamedRanges:

```
=droplist(IF(A1="x", INDIRECT("NamedRangeX"), IF(...) ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## EXAMPLE 1:

[image]

### Sheet1:

**D20: Data Validation > List of items: `I made a choice,I didn't make a choice`**

**F20: Data Validation > List from a range: `Sheet2!D8:D11`**

### Sheet2:

**D8: `=IF(Sheet1!D20 = B6; QUERY(B8:B11;;-1);IF(Sheet1!D20 = C6; QUERY(C8:C11;;-1);))`**

---

## EXAMPLE 2:

**formula in D2:**

```
=IF(A2=F2, {H3:H},
 IF(A2=F3, {I3:I},
 IF(A2=F4, {J3:J}, )))
```

[image]

**data validation in A2:**

> [image]

**data validation in B2:**

> [image]

### **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JTMmtgUck4J5Fm0wiuCN_TUIDA8pzmET4pvswYawc4/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: I cannot try the drop-downs in the demo sheet because it's view only.

Comment: make yourself a copy of that sheet

Comment: Also this works well if you only need a few dynamic drop-downs, but I need to do this easily for hundreds of rows. It will be too bulky if you need a data-validation staging area for each instance of dynamic drop menus.